# Action that returns partial view of all the items in my Session["cart"]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

With Ajax I am able to add ProductIDs to my cart list in my action AddToCart.

This is the code for that:

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int productID)
{
    List<int> cart = (List<int>)Session["cart"];
    if (cart == null){
       cart = new List<int>();
    }
    cart.Add(productID);

    Session["cart"] = cart;

    return new JsonResult() { Data = new { Status = "Success" } };
}
```

In my repository I have this following LINQ method to grab the details on the product by ID:

```
public Products GetProductByID(int id)
{
    return db.Products.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
}
```

Products have Name, Description and Price as attributes.

I have a ViewModel that use for model-binding:

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

I have another Viewmodel that holds this ProductsViewModel, Its the ProductList that I loop thru with foreach:

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
    {
        public List<ProductsViewModel> Productlist { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I need to create a action ie ShoppingCart which should return a partial view of all items in the Session["cart"]. So I can display them in my view with the products details

the action should not need any parameter. It will just look into session and return back a model with the list of products selected.

Something im 100% sure of is that inside the ShoppingCart View I will 100% use following code line:

```
@model AvanShop.ViewModels.HomeIndexViewModel
```

and then do a foreach loop that looks like this:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Productlist)
            {
             code to display the products that are inside the cart  
            }
```

This is an example on how I did my Action index that displays all of the products in my Index view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Productlist = repository.GetAllProducts();
            var model = new HomeIndexViewModel()
            {
                Productlist = new List<ProductsViewModel>()
            };

            foreach (var Product in Productlist)
            {
                FillProductToModel(model, Product);
            }
            return View(model);
        }

private void FillProductToModel(HomeIndexViewModel model, ProductImages productimage)
{
    var productViewModel = new ProductsViewModel
    {

        Description = productimage.Products.Description,
        ProductId = productimage.Products.Id,
        price = productimage.Products.Price,
        Name = productimage.Products.Name,
        Image = productimage.ImageUrl,
    };
    model.Productlist.Add(productViewModel);
}
```

I have no idea how do this, any tips or help is appreciated

Comment: Are you merely asking to see the `List<int>` in `Session["cart"]`, or are you asking how to convert those IDs into a list of actual product details? The former seems pretty trivial, the latter would require you to show use what the product details class looks like, and how to retrieve them.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to be able to display these products with their data from the database on a view. I wonder how I can use my Session["cart"] in the new action ie getshoppingcar so I can use my repository to get the product by ID

Comment: I will edit my question in second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I'd recommend the action be called `ShoppingCart`, and not `GetShoppingCart`; that plays nicer into the conventions of MVC, but that's a minor point and not required.

```
public ActionResult GetShoppingCart()
{
    var cart = Session["cart"] as List<int>;

    var products = cart != null ? cart.Select(id => 
             {
                 var product = GetProductById(id);
                 return new ProductsViewModel
                    {
                       Name = product.Name,
                       Description = product.Description,
                       price = product.Price
                    }
             }) : new List<ProductsViewModel>();

    return PartialView(products);
}
```

And your view (I assume you're using Razor views), `Views/{your controller name}/GetShoppingCart.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductsViewModel>

@if(Model.Any())
{
   The following items are in your cart:
   <ul>
   @foreach(var product in Model)
   {
      <li>@product.Name - @product.Price.ToString("{0:C}")</li>
   }
   </ul>
}
else
{
   You have no items in your shopping cart.
}
```

Comment: About the action should it be var products = cart etc?

Comment: Yes, typo. I corrected my answer.

Comment: about @model IEnumerable<ProductsViewModel> It cant find the ViewModel

Shall I go with "@model Project.ViewModels.HomeIndexViewModel" instead?

Comment: You can give it the full namespace-qualified name of ProductsViewModel. I'm not sure what that is, but it should be in the .CS file for ProductsViewModel. Just paste that namespace declaration in before `ProductsViewModel` in the `@model` declaration, e.g.: `@model Project.ViewModels.ProductViewModel`. If ProductViewModel is in a separate library, make sure your MVC application references that library.

Comment: I think I know why it didnt work, its beacuse I have another viewmodel that has a list of ProductViewModel I updated my question with it

Comment: Also I am recieving this error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.Int32,AvanShop.ViewModels.ProductsViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'AvanShop.ViewModels.ProductsViewModel'.

Comment: I figure it out you were right